# Asp.NetCore bringing table into existing DbContext

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I have successfully created a `DbContext` with tables in asp.netcore.

However, I have realized there are a few more tables that I need to add.  I know that `.edmx` files and updating the database model are no longer available in .netcore and was wondering if it is possible to automatically generate these tables into classes if the `dbcontext` has already been created.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the tables in your DB and then Scaffold. Your models will be updated.

To Scaffold, open `Package Manager Console` in Visual Studio and add the following line and enter:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "ServerYourServerName;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;UserId=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f
```

I know I am late to answer, I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn the Entity Framework core migration using CLI/Package Console, it will create migration snapshot classes files and you need to examine the apply migration, you can refer [Migrations - EF Core with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EntityFramework Core, and just search it up online, you can get a ton of tutorials on how to do it. I learned it in only one day.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do that.

1. Get all the table from database from this query write in package manager console.

   **Scaffold-DbContext "ServerYourServerName;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;UserId=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f**
2. if you want specific table from database then run this query.

   **Scaffold-DbContext "ServerYourServerName;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;UserId=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t "TableName"-f**

Answer (score 0):

you need to download few **Nuget Package Manager** from visual Studio editor.

1. Microsoft.aspnetcore.EntityFrameworkcore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Just search above mentioned package in NuGet package manager and install with same versions which matches with asp.net core.

after this just update your model classes properly and add `DbSet<> in Datacontext class.`

after you have completed all your work . just open package-manager console by going tools from upper menu header in visual studio code. then write below mentioned command.

`PM> add-migration`

second after completing build write next command

`PM> update-database.`

It will look like this you can replace Identity with anything as you wish

`PM> add-migration identity`

> Build started... Build succeeded. To undo this action, use
> Remove-Migration.

`PM> update-database`

> Build started... Build succeeded. Done.

just boom all your database will get update with new tables.